# Go back with router link throw error in router?

Tags: angular

Hi When I click on send message button code working fine with router but when I click there on goback link the code sends error on console and it stops.

You can check in stackbliz of my edit link as : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-communicating-between-components-qjhrpu?file=app%2Ffeedback%2Ffeedback.component.html

Comment: I've voted to close, because the code is no longer available at the provided link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to subscribe assign value to `this.subscription`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.messageService.getNewUserInfo().subscribe(info => {
    this.message = info;
    console.log("here",info);
  })
}
```

After that also check on it's value on `ngOnDestroy`.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    if(this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes Abhishek it also need to check as after back message are taken in memory..Thanks you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to affect your subscription otherwise your `this.subscription` is undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.messageService.getNewUserInfo().subscribe(info => {
    this.message = info;
    console.log("here",info);
  })
}
```

Comment: To manage you subscription, you should take a look at this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)